# Rendering the uploaded file in a wp.media object

Tags: media, media-library, media-modal

I have seen this question asked a few times on SO and I don't see any responses.

I have a wp.media object (upload dialog), that I am using in to store an upload to a post as a meta element. It works fine, except the ul.attachments frame is not refreshing upon upload, see the screenshot

[image: ul.attachments frame]

I have to manually refresh the page to get the new file (pdf.pdf in my screenshot example) to display.

Is there an uploaded event that I can hook into and re-render the view for the file list frame?

Thanks.

**EDIT: I abstracted out the code so that I can demonstrate the issue. N.B. this is using extremely bad practices, but it was the easiest way to abstract.**

Steps to replicate the issue:

1. Drop https://gist.github.com/matgargano/36e76cf4bb2b55e88981 into theme and include it
2. Go to add a post, click "set pdf" in the metabox at the very bottom
3. Drag and drop a PDF, note that the left panel doesn't refresh
4. Refresh the post created/edit page and click "Set pdf" and see the
   panel appears as expected (with the PDF listed on the left hand
   side). *** The goal is to have the left panel refresh in step 3

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I can hold your hand and tap your shoulder while you are waiting for an answer that probably won't come. All media related stuff is completely undocumented JS core code that no body knows how to get around. Possibly not even the ones who wrote it in the first place. Take that +1 - I know it's just a small comfort - for all that pain you will suffer while trying to find an answer.

Comment: You flagged this to change bounty description, but I don't think that's an option. Just comment accordingly or make an edit to your question about it.

Comment: The bounty text should say "If you can get it so the LEFT sidebar refreshes, take the 50!"

Comment: Can you post the code that calls the media modal?

Comment: I use upload dialog in some projects without your issue. Please, post the code and the context so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: ok so I abstracted out what I am trying to accomplish... N.B. this is using extremely bad practices, but it was the easiest way to abstract. Steps to replicate the issue.  

1. Drop https://gist.github.com/matstars/36e76cf4bb2b55e88981 into theme and include it

2. Go to add a post, click "set pdf" in the metabox at the very bottom

3. Drag and drop a PDF, note that the left panel doesn't refresh

4. Refresh the post created/edit page and click "Set pdf" and see the panel appears as expected (with the PDF listed on the left hand side). *** The goal is to have the left panel refresh in step 3

Comment: I think the library option only likes a string - try changing `$mime_types = array( etc` to `$mime_types = 'application/pdf'`.

Comment: You may like [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112559/wordpress-custom-upload-field-error#answer-112574).

Comment: The gist at the provided url has been deleted... Would be great if you can find that snippet and include it in the question... I'm having the same issue but I need that part too in order to fix it :)

Comment: sorry - i'll update it now (https://gist.github.com/matgargano/36e76cf4bb2b55e88981)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presume you've fixed this already but (in a blatant attempt to snaffle the bounty and) as mentioned in the comments there's a simple fix, in your `myplugin_meta_box_callback()` function change the line

```
$mime_types      = array( 'application/pdf' );
```

to

```
$mime_types      = 'application/pdf';
```

The `library.type` option to `wp.media` expects a string (which can be comma-separated with additional types) not an array.

This actually threw up a bug in the `media.model.Attachments` because if you look at where it was failing, the validator `type()` filter (line 997 in "media-models.js")

```
        type: function( attachment ) {
            var type = this.props.get('type');
            return ! type || -1 !== type.indexOf( attachment.get('type') );
        },
```

then what this isn't taking account of is that an attachment type like `application/pdf` is split into type and subtype by `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js()` in "media.php", and this is only validating type, ie `application` (and validating in a pretty sloppy way too with no delimiters).

Anyway all that's moot if you add the [upload validator](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/97025/57034) given by @Bainternet - here's a variation of it:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', function () {
    add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', function ( $file ) {
        if ( empty( $_POST['allowed_mime_types'] ) || empty( $file['type'] ) ) {
            return $file;
        }
        $allowed_mime_types = explode( ',', $_POST['allowed_mime_types'] );
        if ( in_array( $file['type'], $allowed_mime_types ) ) {
            return $file;
        }
        // Cater for "group" allowed mime types eg "image", "audio" etc. to match
        // files of type "image/png", "audio/mp3" etc.
        if ( ( $slash_pos = strpos( $file['type'], '/' ) ) > 0 ) {
            if ( in_array( substr( $file['type'], 0, $slash_pos ), $allowed_mime_types ) ) {
                return $file;
            }
        }
        $file['error'] = __( 'Sorry, you cannot upload this file type for this field.' );
        return $file;
    } );

    add_filter( 'media_view_settings', function ( $settings, $post ) {
        $settings['mimeTypes']['application/pdf'] = __( 'All PDF items' );
        return $settings;
    }, 10, 2 );
} );
```

(The additional `media_view_settings` filter just changes the select filter text from "All media items" to "All PDF items".)
You can then set the `allowed_mime_types` param (in the new way mentioned by @estepix) in your `openModal()` function directly after calling `wp.media()`

```
                this.modal = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media(options);
                if (options.library && options.library.type && this.modal.uploader) {
                    this.modal.uploader.options.uploader.params.allowed_mime_types = options.library.type;
                }
```

and non-PDF files won't be allowed to be uploaded.

Comment: Updated `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` filter to cater for "group" mime types (eg "image", "audio", "video" etc).